# Display buttons based on the user roles in ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-5, user-roles

I have to display the buttons in the view based on the roles, let's say I have roles like admin user and default user wherein admin user will be able to see the delete, modify and add buttons but default user can only search. Currently, when a user logs in I am capturing the userid and sending the userid to the database to get the role of a user and I am storing those roles in session. In the view retrieving the role value using below code

```
@if (Session["UserRole"].ToString() == "Admin")
                {
                    //show delete,modify and create buttons
                }
```

but in my production, the code will be hosted on multiple servers and request can go to any of the servers.

My question is it a good practice to store the roles in the session, is there any better approach to solve my requirement. If I am going with the session in the production environment where there will be multiple servers will the session approach works?

Answer (score 0):

You can have some performance problems with this solution, so I recommend to get the role in the action method and storage this in a ViewData.

But I think that the best solution is to create a partial view with this and in the method an authorize tag.

Comment: I don't want to call DB to get the roles on each and every request, with the ViewBag the value will be there for only one request so it can't be done and with the partial view, I don't think that is the correct solution because I have a button where I have to hide or display based on the role so I cannot create a partial view only for the button.